# Can't set divs in the same line

Tags: html, css

Well,
I Have a pretty complex markup with `css`, and tried to set them div next to div in the usual way but it doesn't work.
So here is the markup of the specific area that I can't set in the same line, here it is:

[image]

```css
ComPS_CtnA {
  margin-top: 3%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.ComPS_CtnA {
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  direction: rtl;
}

.CompP_CtnA {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  margin-top: 1%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ComPH_A,
.comPTCtn {
  width: 100%;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}

.comPTP_A {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.diamondSymbol {
  color: #14366b;
}

.comPTT_A {
  color: #33558a !important;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="ComPS_CtnA clearfix">
  <div class="CompP_CtnA clearfix">
    <h5 class="ComPH_A">
      <span class="diamondSymbol">♦ </span>
      Blablablablabla
    </h5>
    <span class="comPTP_A">[abcdefg]</span>
    <div class="comPTCtn clearfix">
      <h5 class="comPTT_A">I want to be in same line with blablablabla</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: css you provided is not in your html code, please add correct code.

Comment: These classes from the CSS don’t even show up in the HTML you have shown. Please make the minimal effort of providing a _proper_ [mcve].

Comment: Ok, thanks. updated.

Comment: float doesn’t work that way. You can only have two items on the same line, if you float the first one left, and the second one right - if you do it the other way around, the second element _has_ to be placed below the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Grid (I think it's the best Way because you can make the Website easy responsive with it):

```css
.CompP_CtnA{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-template-areas: 'item1 item2' '. item3';
}

.comPTCtn{
    grid-area: item1;
}

.ComPH_A{
    grid-area: item2;
}

.item3{
    grid-area: item3;
}

.float{
    float: right;
}

.diamondSymbol {
    color: #14366b;
}

.comPTT_A {
    color: #33558a;
}
```

```html
<div class="ComPS_CtnA clearfix">
    <div class="CompP_CtnA clearfix">
        <h5 class="ComPH_A">
            <div class="float"><span class="diamondSymbol">♦ </span> Blablablablabla</div>
        </h5>
        <div class="item3"><span class="comPTP_A float">[abcdefg]</span></div>
        <div class="comPTCtn clearfix">
            <h5 class="comPTT_A">I want to be in same line with blablablabla</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution that works for my problem

Comment: @RoiSadika your Welcome :D

Answer (score 0):

Replace This :

```
.ComPH_A, .comPTCtn  {
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

float is a property used for make adjecent item alined to left or right or center.

Comment: Nothing happen.. :|

Comment: apply the same thing in this class too. diamondSymbol of span element

Comment: and why is drection property is there ..try after removing that

Comment: But I need this class to stay at the right side.. all I want to do is to set the <h5> with the class "comPTT_A" to be in the same line with "ComPH_A".

Comment: then do not use 100% width. I think it overtakes the line segment

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code like this. You are using flexbox so no need to use float:

```css
.ComPS_CtnA {
  margin-top: 3%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between; /* This is what you need */
  direction: rtl;
  margin-right:2.5%
}


.diamondSymbol {
  color: #14366b;
}

.comPTT_A {
  color: #33558a;
}
```

```html
<div class="ComPS_CtnA clearfix">
  <div class="CompP_CtnA">
    <h5 class="ComPH_A"><span class="diamondSymbol">♦ </span>Blablablablabla</h5>
    <span class="comPTP_A">[abcdefg]</span>
  </div>

  <div class="comPTCtn ">
    <h5 class="comPTT_A">I want to be in same line with blablablabla</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the float left and float right technique.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#item1 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

#item2 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Above
</div>
<div id="item1">
  Left
</div>
<div id="item2">
  Right
</div>
<div>
  Underneath
</div>
```